# Reference MMDevice API in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, audio, windows-7, windows-vista

I've been reading about the [MMDevice API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows Vista/7. Does anyone know how to reference this API in a C# project. Bonus points if you can provide a simple example on using the API.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. [Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control)

Comment: A newer and more voluminous version can be found here: http://whenimbored.xfx.net/2011/01/core-audio-for-net/